# Can't connect to specific FTP?

Tags: macos, networking, router, vpn, ftp

Have a bit of an issue and I'm pretty confused by this one.

Yesterday I was connecting to my FTP all day and it seemed to be fine but now I'm having issues.  I use a VPN and I'm not sure how that could mess up connecting to my FTP, but my server host made sure my IP has been whitelisted and they can log into my ftp fine with my information.  My ftp details work fine when I check with http://ftptest.net and I tried removing my router and connecting directly to my modem to see if that would help and ti doesnt.. I have tried multiple FTP clients and that didnt work either.  I opened terminal and I tried to "ping" the website and I get no response at all but I get a response back from another website thats hosted on the same IP. What else can I check? It seems like the website is blocked somehow but I have no idea where to look

Answer (score 0):

> I opened terminal and I tried to "ping" the website and I get no response at all but I get a response back from another website thats hosted on the same IP.

Ping is only by IP, so it should not be a difference which hostname for the same IP you use.
Which gives the only explanations that either your hostname cannot be resolved at all (which would also cause ftp and others to fail) or that it resolves to a different IP (where maybe no FTP is). Try `nslookup hostname` or `dig hostname` to find out, if it resolves to an IP at all and if this is the expected IP.

Comment: it doesnt resolve to an IP but when I connect to a VPN, and then try nslookup it works perfectly.  even pinging the website sends packets perfectly fine.. so what is it about my IP thats causing an issue?? I don't get it

Comment: As long as nslookup does not return an IP FTP will not work too because it also cannot get the IP from the hostname. So does FTP only fail if you are not using the VPN, or does it also fail if you are connected to the VPN (and ping and nslookup work)? If it fails with VPN too try `telnet your-ftp-host 21` and add what you get to the question.